# Inherited abstract class with JPA + Circular reference

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, inherited

I have an abstract class AbstractEntity that contains two fields:

- lastEditTime (LocalDateTime)
- lastEditUser (UserEntity)

Below is the code:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    protected LocalDateTime lastEditTime;

    protected UserEntity lastEditUser;

    protected AbstractEntity () { }

    protected AbstractEntity (UserEntity creatorUser) {
        lastEditTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        lastEditUser = creatorUser;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLastEditTime() {
        return lastEditTime;
    }

    public void setLastEditTime(LocalDateTime lastEditTime) {
        this.lastEditTime = lastEditTime;
    }

    public UserEntity getLastEditUser() {
        return lastEditUser;
    }

    public void setLastEditUser(UserEntity lastEditUser) {
        this.lastEditUser = lastEditUser;
    }
}
```

Then I have the UserEntity class that has many different fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class UserEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    private String name;

    private String password;

    ...

}
```

Eclipse shows the following error message:

> In implied association override "lastEditUser", join column "lastEditUser_name" cannot be resolved on table "users"

What does it mean? How can I resolve it?

thanks!

Comment: It's unusual that the abstract mapped superclass is referencing the subclass (in your constructor). This should probably be just the abstract class?

Comment: My intention is to have just one table ("Users"), that contains a column with a Foreign Key to the Primary Key of Users. The column must allow null values. How can I represent that with JPA? My first approach was having the id instead of the object (String instead of UserEntity) .. but the literature says I should reference objects, not IDs. Am I right?

Comment: The message tells you that there is no lastEditUser_name column in the users table. This is the column which is supposed to contain the foreign key to the user that last edited the User entity instance.

Comment: If I change "protected UserEntity lastEditUser;"  by "protected String lastEditUser;" I get the same error message. So, the problem is not the circular reference.

Comment: JB Nizet. Should I manually create manually the column in the table? I thought JPA does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disconnected eclipse Datasource. Then I clean the project (the error messages were gone), then I deleted the tables in the database, and finally I run a test case to recreate the tables.

The new table has the two inherited columns.